# inline-block vs. block: why does adding a "border" change inner height?

Tags: html, css

I've noticed that adding a border to `display:block` elements changes the way they respect inner elements' `margin-top` values.

In the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/vbmaxgh0/2/, why does the "border-less" block element not render with the same size as the "border" block element or the "inline-block" element?

Comment: Its because the collapsing margins check this out - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing

Comment: if you want both the div to be of same size use `box-sizing:border-box` which will give `border` `padding` from inside

Comment: because it is how html is built like, but as @VitorinoFernandes has said, some frameworks like twitter bootstrap used the line of code for convenience.

Comment: Other comments, I think you didn't understand my question...I'm not referring to the fact that adding a border adds more size in the box model, but to the fact that the 'display:block' div didn't treat its childs' margin the same way as the other divs.

Comment: @MaryMelody Thanks! I get it now - the margin of the inner child collapsed with the margin of the parent div and ended up OUTSIDE the parent div, since it is a block element. Please place your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this issue because of the margin collapsing:

> The adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not
>   be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine
>   this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is
>   called a collapsed margin.

**Source: [W3C - 8.3.1 Collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)**

You could also add `overflow: auto;` to the `#block` to fix the issue.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ydLfqxut/)**

```
#block {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto; /* or overflow: hidden; */
}
```

Further Reading::

> [Mozilla MDN - Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)